# Why can't I use head directly in this linked list problem instead of initializing and using ptr?

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I was going through this solution for implementing a doubly linked list when I came across this doubt

```java
public class Solution
{
    public static Node constructDLL(int []arr) {
        Node head = new Node(arr[0]);
        Node ptr = head;
        for(int i = 1; i<arr.length; i++) {
            Node node = new Node(arr[i]);
            ptr.next = node;
            node.prev = ptr;
            ptr = node;
        }
        return head;
    }
}
```

Why can't I use head directly in this linked list problem instead of initializing and using ptr like this?

```java
public class Solution
{
    public static Node constructDLL(int []arr) {
        Node head = new Node(arr[0]);
  
        for(int i = 1; i<arr.length; i++) {
            Node node = new Node(arr[i]);
            head.next = node;
            node.prev = head;
            head= node;
        }
        return head;
    }
}
```

And if ptr refers to head, why does returning ptr return one value but returning head returns all the values in the array? I'm new to linked list and these things have got me super confused.

Comment: When you are creating a linked-list, you are adding a new element at the `next` of the last element. `ptr` in your first case keeps track of that last element. In the second approach you are just replacing the first element every time.

Comment: Look carefully. `head` is never modified in the method while `ptr` is. So these variables do not contain the same value and hence, are not interchangeable. All your other questions are about consequences of that difference.

Answer (score 1):

If you would perform `return ptr` instead of `return head` in the first solution, you would actually do the same as in the second. The name of the variable that you use in the `return` statement is of course not of importance; it is the node (reference) that you return that is important.

And so it is clear that with that modification you return the *last* node that was appended to the list (see last iteration of the loop). That node has its `next` field still at `null`. The caller would have to navigate via the `prev` references back to the head to eventually find it.

Answer (score 0):

Initializing a node as `head` and using `ptr` for traversal helps in visualizing the `head` node as the starting point of the doubly linked list. If you use `head` directly to build the doubly linked list, you will lose the starting node and later, you will have to traverse backwards to get the starting node.

If you return `ptr` in the first case, then `ptr` is the last node of the linked list and hence will return only one node, whereas `head` is the first node and will return all the nodes.